# Revert back yum update

Tags: centos6, yum

I have recently tried to yum install a package, along which it updated (automatically) update httpd, httpd-devel, httpd-tools packages I don't wish to update. Reason being these were custom packages.

A run using `yum history info <id>`, it shows:

```
...
Packages Altered:
...
Updated     httpd-2.2.15-28.el6.centos.x86_64            @updates
Update            2.2.15-60.el6.centos.6.x86_64          @updates
Updated     httpd-devel-2.2.15-28.el6.centos.x86_64      @updates
Update                  2.2.15-60.el6.centos.6.x86_64    @updates
Updated     httpd-tools-2.2.15-28.el6.centos.x86_64      @updates
Update                  2.2.15-60.el6.centos.6.x86_64    @updates
...
```

Currently everything runs like previously, I suppose I haven't yet perform any reboot. Question is, are the httpd packages changed? And if so, what are better ways to revert back as this is production environment so minimum downtime preferred.

Answer (score 5):

With the id you already used in `yum history info <id>` you can just roll back the installation of the updates if you want to:

```
yum history undo/redo/rollback <id>
```

Which of the commands you want to use is up to what you want to do. From `man yum`:

> The undo/redo commands act on the specified transaction, undo'ing or repeating the work of that transaction.  While the rollback command will undo all transactions up to the point of the specified transaction. For example, if you have 3 transactions, where package A; B  and  C  where  installed  respectively.   Then "undo 1" will try to remove package A, "redo 1" will try to install package A (if it is not still installed), and "rollback 1" will try to remove packages B and C. Note that after  a  "rollback  1"  you  will  have  a  fourth transaction, although the ending rpmdb version (see: yum version) should be the same in transactions 1 and 4.

Regarding the second part of your question, have the packages changed:

Of course they have, otherwise there wouldn't be a newer version of the package. You can compare the content of the packages with the content of the previous version, but the version change in your case is so minute that I wouldn't bother. The version of the software contained in the package hasn't changed, it's just something changed by the maintainer of the package itself.

Since you are doing all this in a testing environment (you are, right?) it should be safe to reboot the server and just try it. You can still revert to the older versions if something unexpected shows up.

Answer (score 2):

In the meantime: `yum history undo <id>` should work.

To save yourself some future headaches I would add `exclude=httpd httpd-devel httpd-tools` to your /etc/yum.conf file:

```
echo "exclude=httpd httpd-devel httpd-tools" >> /etc/yum.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try explicitely downgrading your packages to the specific version that was still useful for your cause:

```
yum downgrade httpd-tools-2.2.15-28.el6
```